# ¿como ocultar inputs al recargar la pagina con js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

Tengo un g:select en el cual se manejan estatus, y cada estatus tiene un input para guardar una fecha, despues de guardar algún estatus se recarga la pagina, el select se queda con el ultimo estatus pero se muestran todos los demás inputs, quiero que solo se muestre la fecha del estatus actual, mi form es:

```
<g:form class="form-horizontal form-bordered"  url="[action:'guardarDetalles',controller:'Coordinacion']" onsubmit="return Valida(this);"  method="POST">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-froup">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label class="control-label">Cambio de Estatus:</label><br>
                                        <g:select class="form-control" id="select"  name="estatus"  from="${asignacionTesis.Estatus.list()}" value="${estatus}" optionKey="id" optionValue="estatus" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 cedula">
                                        <label for="" class="control-label">Fecha asignación de Grado</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="datepicker4" value="${finalizada}" class="form-control" name="asignacionGrado" placeholder="Selecciona la fecha" autocomplete="false">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 cedula1">
                                        <label for="" class="control-label">Fecha de detención</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="datepicker1"value="${detencion}" class="form-control" name="fechaDetencion" placeholder="Selecciona la fecha" autocomplete="false">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 cedula2">
                                            <label for="" class="control-label">Fecha de reapertura</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="form-control" value="${reapertura}" name="fechaReapertura" placeholder="Selecciona la fecha" autocomplete="true">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4" >

                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="idTesis" value="${params.id}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                             <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <div class="form-group no-border">
                                        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"></label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                                            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Limpiar</button>

                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </g:form>
```

el script del select es:

```
    $('#select').on('change',function(){
    var selectValor = $(this).val();               

    if (selectValor == '1') {
    $('.cedula').hide();
    }else {
    $('.cedula').hide();                    
        }
     });

    $('#select').on('change',function(){
    var selectValor = $(this).val();   
    if (selectValor == '4') {
    $('.cedula').show();

    }else {
    $('.cedula').hide();       
   }

     });
    $('#select').on('change',function(){
    var selectValor = $(this).val();               

    if (selectValor == '2') {
    $('.cedula1').show();
    }else {
    $('.cedula1').hide();                    
        }
     });

    $('#select').on('change',function(){
    var selectValor = $(this).val();

    if (selectValor == '3') {
    $('.cedula2').show();
    }else {
    $('.cedula2').hide();                    
    }

     });
```

Entonces cuando se recarga la pagina si se queda con el ultimo estatus pero se muestran todos los inputs, lo que busco es que solo se muestre la fecha del select

Answer (score 1):

Parece que el problema es que se actualiza el formulario con los valores pero no se dispara el evento "change" del select cuando es cargado con los valores iniciales, no conozco los componentes `g:xxx`, pero la idea sería disparar a mano el evento una vez se haya cargado el valor en el `g:select` con la variable `status`.

Me falta contexto (el código donde se cargan los valores) para saber exactamente dónde hay que añadirlo, pero la línea sería esta:

```
$('#select').trigger('change');
```

Si no estás seguro de dónde colocarla, prueba una vez cargada la página:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#select').trigger('change');
});
```

Por otro lado, no se necesitan 4 "handlers" para cada posible valor del select, es más eficiente y más sencillo uno único, por ejemplo:

```
$("#select").on("change", function() {
  var selectValor = $(this).val();

  $(".cedula").hide();
  $(".cedula1").hide();
  $(".cedula2").hide();

  if (selectValor == "4") {
    $(".cedula").show();
  } else if (selectValor == "2") {
    $(".cedula1").show();
  } else if (selectValor == "3") {
    $(".cedula2").show();
  }
});
```